# $X_{n}$ bounded for all but finitely many $n$ implies $\sup_{n} X_{n}$ bounded

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots$ be iid random variables. Suppose for some $M$ we knew that $P(\limsup \{X_{n} >M\}) = 0$, that is, it is almost never do we have $X_{n} > M$ infinitely often. Does this imply that $\sup_{n} X_{n}$ is finite?

This seems true. Since we have almost never have $X_{n} > M$ infinitely often, then $X_{n} \leq M$ for all but finitely many $n$. Then $\sup_{n} X_{n}$ is finite. But I seem to have issue writing this out in terms of sets. We have
$P(\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{m = n}^{\infty}\{X_{m} > M\}) = 0$ and hence $P(\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{m = n}^{\infty}\{X_{m} \leq M\}) = 1$. I want to show that $P(\sup_{n} X_{n} < \infty) = 1$. How do I relate this expression to $P(\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{m = n}^{\infty}\{X_{m} \leq M\})$?

Comment: what do you mean by $\lim\sup\{X_n>M\}$?

Comment: I mean limsup of the sets $\{X_{n} > M\}$ (which are indexed by $n$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without involving these expressions.

$$\sup X_n(\omega)=\infty\implies X_n(\omega)>M\text{ i.o.}$$

This for all $\omega\in\Omega$ so: $$\{\sup X_n=\infty\}\subseteq\limsup\{X_n>M\}$$

hence:$$P(\{\sup X_n=\infty\})\leq P(\limsup\{X_n>M\})=0$$